# Обращение к локальному файлу из браузера

Tags: air, flash, javascript, java, actionscript

Доброго времени суток. Встала необходимость написания скрипта, который бы получал информацию из файла пользователя и выводил её в браузер. На HTML5 смог сделать только нечто подобное с помощью FileAPI - открывалось окно, в котором выбирался нужный *.txt файл и его содержимое через innerHTML выводилось в браузер. Корректно пока работает лишь в FireFox последней версии.
Вопрос - могут ли какие-нибудь другие технологии (ActionScript + Flash / Air, Java) подобное, но без необходимости выбирать файл? Например, при установке необходимого сертификата.

Comment: Для webmoney, кажется, это как-то делают.

Comment: тоже пришло на ум... у них там как раз и используется доверительный сертификат.

Answer (score 1):

В Java можно просто открыть нужный файл и всё. Только нужно, чтобы приложение было подписано, иначе ему не дадут доступ к файловой системе.

**UPD**

Вы не сразу раскрыли свои цели. Если вы хотите просто дать "нужным" людям доступ к файлу, а доступ к нему приравнивать к возможности авторизоваться, то зачем так сложно-то делать? Ну так и сделайте серверную часть так, чтобы он принимал людей из нужных подсетей без всяких паролей. Либо используйте сертификат в качестве метода авторизации и расшарьте "своим" людям этот сертификат.

Comment: то есть, прямое обращение к файлу по адресу типа "D:\File\filename.txt" без диалоговых окон (меня как раз это и интересовало)?

Comment: Ну да.. просто как обычное чтение из файла

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле FileApi поддерживают все последние броузеры. ДАЖЕ IE (9й)!

И зачем вам файл ? Может вам достаточно будет локального хранилища (LocalStorage) ?

Или даже куки ?

Comment: нет, shurik, к сожалению, куки не подойдут. LocalStorage, по-моему, будут хранить данные только в период одной сессии, а эти данные в этот LocalStorage нужно преждевременно поместить. Вообще, идея с куками хорошая, но как быть, если, допустим, я бы хотел хранить файлы на расшаренном диске, а доступ в пределе домена будут получать пользователи через браузер?  
То есть, например, файлы с логинами и паролями хранятся на расшаренном диске, пользователи получают доступ к данным только находясь в одной подсети.